# Let $W \subset V^*$ and consider as a bilinear form the natural pairing. Is $(W^\perp)^\perp = W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, bilinear-form, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and consider its dual, $V^*$. The **natural pairing** is the bilinear functional defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
 \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : V^* \times V &\to \mathbb{F} \\
(f, \mathbf{v}) & \mapsto \langle f, \mathbf{v}\rangle := f(\mathbf{v}).
\end{align*}

Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. We define the **orthogonal complement** of $U$, $U^\perp$, as
$$U^\bot := \{f \in V^* :\, \forall \mathbf{u} \in U \ ( \langle f, \mathbf{v}\rangle = 0)\}.$$

Now consider a subspace of $V^*$, $W$. Its orthogonal complement is defined as
$$W^\bot := \{\mathbf{v} \in V :\, \forall f \in W \ ( \langle f, \mathbf{v}\rangle = 0)\}.$$

By definition we have that $W \subset (W^\perp)^\perp$. My question is: Is $(W^\perp)^\perp = W$?

Attempt at counterexample: Consider the vector space $V$ of all the real functions defined on $\mathbb R$. Let $W \subset V^*$ be the subspace spanned by all pointwise evaluations, $W = \text{span }\big(\{\delta_{x} :\, x \in \mathbb R\}\big)$, where $\delta_x : V \to \mathbb R$ maps $f \mapsto f(x)$.
The orthogonal complement $W^\bot$ contains only the zero function. On the other hand, $(W^\perp)^\perp = V^*$ because in general there is no finite linear combination of pointwise evaluations that generates, for instance, the mean of a function, $(W^\perp)^\perp \setminus W \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: If $\dim V$ is infinite the natural map $V\to V^{**}$ is injective but not surjective, and $W^{\perp \perp} = \overline{W}$ (closure).

Comment: Are you sure there are no other functionals?  Ones from the Axiom of Choice, for example?  The zero functional on $W$ has many extensions to functionals on $V$.